# Fetching data in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have `<table>` that display data. I have a button if I click, the data will be displayed in `#datacontainer`. But the problem is only first row in my table is shown.

Here's my code

HTML - here's the table, imagine that I have 4 data in my table (DATABASE) but the first row only shows the data when you click the button.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th width="15%;">Image</th>
    <th width="0">ID</th>
    <th width="50%;">Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
 <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($accounts)) { ?>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="images/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?><input type="text" id="text_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?>, <?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <i class="fab fa-reddit-alien" id="showdatacontainer" onclick="return chk()"></i>
        <i class="far fa-edit"  style="margin: 0 7% 0 7%;"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
<div id="datacontainer"></div>
```

Javascript - and here's my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function chk()
    {
    $("#datacontainer").slideToggle(300);
    var id = document.getElementById('text_id').value;
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "showdata.php",
      data:dataString,
      cache:false,
      success: function(data){
        $("#datacontainer").html(data);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

PHP - and here's my PHP code "showdata.php"

```
    <?php 
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'psbr');
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

    $id = $_POST['id']; 
    $accounts = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from accounts where id = '$id'");
    }

 ?>

 <table>
 <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($accounts)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="w"><h1>Name</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
 </table>
 <style type="text/css">
.w
{
    font-size: 12vh;
}
 </style>
```

please help me out of this problem thankyou! :D

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: do you think that is database problem? or in my code?

Answer (score -1):

You are grabbing the value by ID, yet there are several elements with the same ID, because you are in a loop, therefore, you will always get the first answer.

```
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?><input type="text" id="text_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
```

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: you should make sure the id is unique, maybe give them all the same class. however you'd still need to find a way of targeting the correct id, and as i dont see `#datacontainer`, it's impossible for me to say

Comment: I already updated my post. When you click the button, the data's will shown in 'datacontainer' but the problem is the first row only show

Comment: I dont see the datacontainer element anywhere in your post